# Is it possible to change grid's lockable separator thickness?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

In an extjs grid component I can specify which columns are locked with the attribute

```
locked: true
```

This leads to the following layout, where (in my example) two columns are locked:

```
locked1 locked2 | field1 field2 ...
```

I'd like for the "|" separator to have a bigger thickness because, as it is now, I find it harder to notice.
Would it be possible?

Comment: Just look into the css and add a custom rule. Or head over to the docs and edit that property in the sass files and compile it into the theme's css.

Comment: Yes that could be a good idea but how's this "separator" called?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following css:

```
.x-grid-locked .x-grid-inner-locked {
    border-width: 0 10px 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify the theme instead of adding custom CSS, [here is the CSS](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.locking.Lockable-css_var-S-grid-lockable-separator-border-width) var (for ExtJs 4.2.2)

You find it in the file `ext/packages/ext-theme-neutral/sass/var/grid/locking/Lockable.scss`.

```
/**
 * @class Ext.grid.locking.Lockable
 */

/**
 * @var {number}
 * The width of the border between the locked views
 */
$grid-lockable-separator-border-width: 1px !default;

/**
 * @var {string}
 * The border-style of the border between the locked views
 */
$grid-lockable-separator-border-style: solid !default;
```

Look into [Theming](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/theming) in the doc to create a custom theme and add this change in it.